# Image (Error) Image.constant: Invalid Image.constant type?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to find actual evapotranspiration by use equation

> ETa = ETf*pet

I import image collection of pet from IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE for 3 years.
When I multiply Etf with pet for finding aet(ETa). I get error

> "Image (Error) Image.constant: Invalid Image.constant type."

```
var aet = ee.Image(ee.Number(mean_etf))
        .multiply(ee.Number(pet))
        .rename('ETa')
        .cast({'ETa': 'float'});

print(aet);

Map.addLayer(aet) ;
```

Mylink : https://code.earthengine.google.com/a311d7d5b0994a0dedd66e10661bd6ba

Comment: Please provide a link to a minimal EE script giving this error, and make sure all used assets are shared.